# How change prop('checked', true) until different element (for example tr) JQUERY/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

How after double click checkbox for example 100 change state on check state and checkbox with value 35.

Or the same thing with 20, after double click checkbox 25 need to change on checked and only this, checkbox with value 100 and 35 I don't need to change state.

I need to get something like if you double click on 300. I need double click on 100 and I need only change state for checkbox with value 100 and 35

```js
$(document).on('dblclick', '.add_campaign_2_excel', function(e) {
    $( ".for_download_campaign").prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="add_campaign_2_excel">
      <input class="for_download_campaign" data-downl_company="300" type="checkbox"> 300
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="expand expand-site"></td>
    <td class="add_site_2_excel">
      <input class="for_download_site" data-downl_insertion="100" type="checkbox"> 100
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="expand expand-site"></td>
    <td class="add_site_2_excel">
      <input class="for_download_site" data-downl_insertion="35" type="checkbox"> 35
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="add_insertion_2_excel">
      <input class="for_download_insertion" data-downl_insertion="110" type="checkbox"> 110
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="add_campaign_2_excel">
      <input class="for_download_campaign" data-downl_company="323" type="checkbox"> 323
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="expand expand-site"></td>
    <td class="add_site_2_excel">
      <input class="for_download_site" data-downl_insertion="20" type="checkbox"> 20
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="expand expand-site"></td>
    <td class="add_site_2_excel">
      <input class="for_download_site" data-downl_insertion="25" type="checkbox"> 25
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="add_insertion_2_excel">
      <input class="for_download_insertion" data-downl_insertion="1" type="checkbox"> 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain the problem in more detail? Maybe you can add some of the code (JavaScript) that you already tried to your question (I moved your code to a snippet view, try add to that).

Comment: And now do you understand?